# Remove and reorder list elments

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Is it possible to solve the following problem **WITHOUT** using C# loop (foreach; for; while; etc) but only C# Linq or lambda expressions?

Problem: 
Given a list of Task objects and a list of removed TaskIds.  I want that list is updated with only elements that are **NOT** in the list of removed TaskIds, and the remaining Task elements are re-ordered, too.

### Details:

```
(1*) Given a list of Task objects:

TaskId  Group   Name    Order


281        1    "abc"   1  
726        1    "dre"   2  // note: will be removed  
9891       1    "euf"   3  // note: will be removed  
87         1    "wop"   4  
932        1    "hjd"   5  

102        2    "fhl"   1  // note: will be removed  
44         2    "bgg"   2  
30         2    "qds"   3  
293        2    "djf"   4  // note: will be removed  
389        2    "hkd"   5  

12         3    "hjf"   1  
900        3    "xdf"   2  // note: will be removed  


(2*) Given a list of removed TaskIds:  
TaskId  
726  
9891  
102  
293  
900
```

Now, after removing list (1*) based on list (2*), I want list (1*) looks like (note: the remaining elements' orders are updated, too):

List (1*) is updated:

```
TaskId  Group   Name    Order  

281        1    "abc"   1  
87         1    "wop"   2  // note: new order  
932        1    "hjd"   3  // note: new order  

44         2    "bgg"   1  // note: new order  
30         2    "qds"   2  // note: new order  
389        2    "hkd"   3  // note: new order  

12         3    "hjf"   1  // note: order is kept unchanged.
```

The Task class is defined like:

```
 public class Task {
      public int TaskId { get;set; }
      public int Group { get; set;}
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Order { get; set;}

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do realise that linq uses iteration (for-loops and whatnot) in the background, right?

Comment: @ J.Steen -  the approach I want to ask is try to avoid using explicit C# loop codes like "for", "foreach", "while" etc.

Comment: Avoiding the actual keywords? I'm curious, what does that accomplish, for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var tasks = new[]{
        new Task{TaskId = 281, Group = 1, Name = "abc", Order =1},
        new Task{TaskId = 726 , Group = 1, Name = "dre", Order =2},
        new Task{TaskId = 9891, Group = 1, Name = "euf", Order =3},
        new Task{TaskId = 102, Group = 2, Name = "wop", Order =1},
        new Task{TaskId = 44, Group = 2, Name = "wop", Order =2},
        new Task{TaskId = 30, Group = 2, Name = "wop", Order =3},
        new Task{TaskId = 293, Group = 2, Name = "wop", Order =4},
        new Task{TaskId = 295, Group = 3, Name = "was", Order =1},
};

int[] itemsToRemove = {726, 102, 293};

tasks.Where(task => !itemsToRemove.Contains(task.TaskId))
     .GroupBy(task => task.Group)
     .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select((task, grpIndex) => 
                                   { task.Order = grpIndex + 1; return task; }));
```

this wiil return:

```
TaskId Group   Name Order
281    1       abc  1 
9891   1       euf  2 
44     2       wop  1  
30     2       wop  2 
295    3       was  1
```

Comment: Thank you Ilya Ivanov. I will try the hints.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Task> tasksList = new List<Task>();
List<int> tasksIds = new List<int>();
List<Task> resultList = tasksList.FindAll(task => !taskIds.Contains(task.TaskId));
```